# VBA transfer data from one workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to write the followings to transfer the data from one workbook to another one, however, it gets the error 9 that is out of script range. I've checked twice and could not locate any mistakes. Could you help to check to see whether I have missed anything or something is wrong? Thanks a lot.

```
Private Sub Transfer_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("List").Select
v = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
Dim a()
Dim b()
ReDim a(v - 1)
ReDim b(v - 1)
Sheets("Yahoo").Select
For i = 0 To v - 1 
a(i) = Cells(i + 7, 4) 
b(i) = Cells(i + 7, 5)
Next

ChDir "C:\Users\Desktop\Data Analysis"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\Data Analysis\Data.xlsx"

Sheets("List").Select
For i = 2 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 
Sheets("List").Select 
k = Cells(i, 1) 
If k = "" Then Exit For 
Sheets(k).Select 
h = Range("B8").End(xlDown).Row 
Cells(h + 1, "B") = a(i - 2) 
Cells(h + 1, "F") = b(i - 2)
Next

Windows("Data.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Yahoo").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Save
Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Successfully transferred!", vb0XOnly, "Notice"


End Sub
```

Comment: At which line error occurrs? The "Data.xlsm" and "Data.xlsx" are separate workbooks, aren't they?

Comment: Avoid `.Select` at all costs, it is the source of many common errors. Maybe the error occurs because you are selecting a range but you don't explicty indicate from which workbook. You could declare something like this: `Dim wb as Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\Data Analysis\Data.xlsx")`. Then you should use `wb.Worksheets("List").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row ` for example.